# Why doesn't Apache Cordova support databases bigger than 50 MB?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

The [offical Apache Cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html) describes 3 ways of storing data:

1. LocalStorage
2. WebSQL
3. IndexedDB

For any application in need of a real database, *LocalStorage* is no option:

> [LocalStorage] only stores strings, so complex data structures have to be serialized, and only data that can be serialized can be stored.

*WebSQL* lacks the possibility of big databases, although my personal experience says their size is typically rather limited to 50MB.

> Limited total amount of storage (typically around 5MB).

*IndexedDB* lacks iOS support and is said to have a ~5MB size restriction too, although my experience says it dependens on the browser.

> Not supported on iOS.
>   Limited total amount of storage (typically around 5MB).

- Is it true that there is **no way to store big databases** using Cordova without using a plugin?
- Why isn't the [cordova-sqlite-plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#readme) part of Cordova and backed by Apache?

Comment: That limit was deliberately added to prevent web pages from using up too much space.

Answer (score 0):

You need see with different eyes, the solutions around world Cordova in my personal opinion are for small storages, in sync with a server provideded for one REST API, running Mysql, Mongo or other services database.

If you need storage big database files inside project, you can use the plugin File: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file

You only have to use the same LocalStorage logic but saving a text file inside the project

Answer (score 0):

We have plenty of work with just the platforms and core plugins that we currently maintain. We welcome anyone who wants to join, and help and commit to the project, and aid the community.

Whether it happens in one of the cordova repos, or somewhere else, the cordova committers will happily send users to wherever a solid plugin is.

To a large extent, I also agree with @diogomachado in that you would/should probably not need to store that much data on a user's device, and there are other ways of doing it (fileAPI).  Many modern project have moved away from sql all together as often the entire relational model, and atomic transactions are not needed.  *How many tables do you have?*

Also, have not used it, but iOS supports IndexedDB in iOS 10.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb

If you would like to help out on this, here's more info on contributing to cordova.
https://cordova.apache.org/contribute/